# Objective-C Memory Management

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I know there are several "similar" questions out there, but I think this is an issue a lot of programmers have issues with and needs extra attention.

Say I have a factory method for a class that returns an autoreleased object:

```
+(id)queueWithDelegate:(id)aDelegate {
    return [[[self alloc] initWithDelegate:aDelegate] autorelease];
}
```

When I call this function and receive my `queue` object, must I explicitly `retain` it, or does the simple fact that I am assigning it to a *variable* do it?

```
MyQueue q = [MyQueue queueWithDelegate:self]; // Does this need to be retained?
```

Or am I confusing this with properties? If I have a property like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, *retain*) myQueue;
// Does the "retain" part of the property mean it's going to automatically add
// to the retain count?

self.myQueue = [MyQueue queueWithDelegate:self]; // Do I need to call retain?
```

I think my issue may be that I've gotten properties mixed up with local variables. Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the retain part of the property does mean that it will automatically retain the property but only when you use the property.

```
//self.xxxx is how you use the property and if retain is set it it will retain your queue
//likewise if copy were set it would copy the queue if possible
self.myQueue = [MyQueue queueWithDelegate:self];
```

Dong the following

```
MyQueue q = [MyQueue queueWithDelegate:self];
```

will not retain your queue automatically since an autoreleased object is expected to be returned by `queueWithDelegate:`. The queue at this point is in the autorelease pool and will be valid within the function called as it is expected to be cleaned up no later than the beginning of the next run loop.

The [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) provides insight into when to expect an autoreleased object, when to retain, and when to release.

Comment: Thanks. I knew those things. It's just way too early in the morning to be coding. Fixed my question.

Comment: And the property will only retain the object if it has the `retain` flag, as opposed to `assign` and `copy`.

Comment: So if I set it to a local variable but then later use the `ivar` instead of the property to store it, I need to specifically call `retain`, correct?

Comment: That is correct. But you will also need to call to release directly on the ivar right before storing it as well. `[myQueue release]; myQueue = [[MyQueue queueWithDelegate:self] retain];`

Comment: Gotcha. So is it preferred to set properties using the actual property instead of ivars?